# How to see if a dataframe column values exist in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe column named 'Ace Code' (`df['Ace Code']`) and would like to check if the column value for each row exists in the list below.

```
codes = ['M6L', 'M8V', 'M9A', 'M9N', 'M2L', 'M4B', 'M4K', 'M4S', 'M5A',\
         'M5J', 'M5R','M6A', 'M6J', 'L4W', 'L5C', 'L5L', 'L3T', 'M2N', \
         'M3M', 'L4T', 'L6R', 'L6Y','L3P', 'M1T', 'M1C', 'M1L', 'L4H',]
```

I tried `df['Ace Code'].isin(codes)` but this returned all False when I know for a fact there are matches. I would like to have a new binary column next to df['Ace Code'] that returns T/F depending on if a match is found in the codes list.

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe

Comment: Working fine for me. Please check your data frame.

Comment: does `df['Ace Code'].str.strip().isin(codes)` work?

Comment: Perhaps there's a data type mismatch between `codes` and `df['Ace Code']`

Comment: please share your dataframe

Comment: May be the matches are not exact, try `str.contains` : `df['Ace Code'].str.contains('|'.join(codes),na=False,case=False)`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this -

```
import pandas as pd

codes = ['M6L', 'M8V', 'M9A', 'M9N', 'M2L', 'M4B', 'M4K', 'M4S', 'M5A',
         'M5J', 'M5R','M6A', 'M6J', 'L4W', 'L5C', 'L5L', 'L3T', 'M2N', 
         'M3M', 'L4T', 'L6R', 'L6Y','L3P', 'M1T', 'M1C', 'M1L', 'L4H',]


other_codes = ['HVH','HKJ','PYU','TRE','QWE']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=codes+other_codes,columns=['Ace Code'])

>>> df['Flag'] = df['Ace Code'].isin(codes)
>>> df
   Ace Code   Flag
0       M6L   True
1       M8V   True
2       M9A   True
3       M9N   True
4       M2L   True
5       M4B   True
6       M4K   True
7       M4S   True
8       M5A   True
9       M5J   True
10      M5R   True
11      M6A   True
12      M6J   True
13      L4W   True
14      L5C   True
15      L5L   True
16      L3T   True
17      M2N   True
18      M3M   True
19      L4T   True
20      L6R   True
21      L6Y   True
22      L3P   True
23      M1T   True
24      M1C   True
25      M1L   True
26      L4H   True
27      HVH  False
28      HKJ  False
29      PYU  False
30      TRE  False
31      QWE  False
```